# Is there a timeline for the naming of the TRAPPIST-1 worlds?

Tags: naming, trappist-1

For the moment, the TRAPPIST-1 worlds are just known by their official designations, like "TRAPPIST-1a" etc. NASA made a casual tweet asking people what they would name the worlds, and there has been some talk of naming the worlds after Belgian beers due to the origin of the "Trappist" name, but I haven't heard any official talk about what names might be given to the new exoplanets.

I'm wondering, is there a timeline (either official or traditional) for the naming of these worlds? Based on previous names given to astronomical bodies, are they likely to have names within the year, or is it likely to take at least five years or something, or is it completely unpredictable?